# How to get array name from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this associative array:

```
Array ( [42] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) [43] => Array ( [quantity] => 3 ) )
```

I need to get those 42 and 43 into string or integer (it is my order_id).

Do you know how?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: @rjdown thanks!! This is the function I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `array_keys` function (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). It returns the keys of an array.